# Retrieve custom form via the API Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'd like to retrieve a list of all custom forms and the label to field name relationships for each form in Netsuite programmatically.  I have looked at SuiteScript and cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done through suitescript. Best way I can think of interacting with this would be through the API on the Suitescript Developer Framework. This can read forms, and will return an XML which you can then use.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method from SOAP API.

```
var customForms = svc.getSelectValue(new GetSelectValueFieldDescription
{
    field = "customForm",
    recordType = RecordType.salesOrder,
    recordTypeSpecified = true
}, 1);
```